# Creating dynamic Mongoose models with prefix

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to create mongoose model dynamically with a prefix variable.

I have a First UserSchema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: String,
blogs : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog' }],
)};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And a BlogShema

```
var BlogSchema = new Schema({
blogName: String,
posts : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: prefix + 'Post' }]
)};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

Then a PostSchema

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
blog: { type: String, ref: 'Blog' },
title: String,
content: String
)};

module.exports = mongoose.model(prefix + 'Post', PostSchema);
```

Each Schema is on separate js files:

1. posts.server.model.js
2. blogs.server.model.js
3. users.server.model.js

I would like the prefix variable in mongoose.model(prefix + 'Post', PostSchema); to get the value of username String from UserSchema which passed form a signup form through

```
require('../../models/users.server.model.js');
require('../../models/blogs.server.model.js');
require('../../models/posts.server.model.js');
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = require('mongoose').model('User'),
    Blog = require('mongoose').model('Blog'),
    Post = require('mongoose').model(prefix + 'Post');
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField : 'username',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
    User.findOne({ username :  username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Username is already taken.'));
        } else {
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.username = username;
            newUser.password = password;
            newUser.email = req.body.email;
            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                var site = new Site({user : newUser.username, siteTitle: newUser.username});
                site.save(function(err) { // create website
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    } else {
                        newUser.sites.push(site); // push site'id in sites field in user
                        newUser.save(); // save user after site'id has been push
                        for (var i=0; i<basePages.length; i++) { // create pages from base.json file
                            var page = new Page(basePages[i]);
                            page.save(function(err, page) { // create page
                                if (err) {
                                    return next(err);
                                } else {
                                    site.pages.push(page); // push page'id in pages field in site
                                    site.save(); // save site after pages'id has been push
                                };
                            });
                        };
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    };
                });
            });
        };
    });  
});
}));
```

For resume, If signup username is **john** during signup I would like to create a **johnpost** collection john posts.

Comment: You should have a single `post` collection, where each document within this collection has a username property.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I would like to do!

Comment: Why do you want to have one collection per user?

Comment: Be cause I simply need it.

Comment: @Artefact Well then, good luck. :)

Comment: I could imagine, that he needs this e.g. when a user gets deleted, he only needs to delete the collection. It is much faster. Also, what if he wants to transfer the user to another system/database? He only needs to transfer the collection, or the increment of documents, instead of first find all related posts.
I need the same. I don't want to have one collection with TB of data. One collection per one of a 1,000 users is much more handy.
I see no reason to have all in one if there is no need of showing merged posts anyway.